# jquery: function in "onclick"

Tags: jquery, html

```
    $('.more').click(function test(id) {
          $('#MoreFriendInfo'+id).toggle();
   });
```

I made this, function test(id), now how should i make the link right in html/php in order to grab the id?
I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
<a class='more' href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='test(<?php echo $showInfo["bID"]; ?>)'>mer</a>
```

In firebug i get "test isnt defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In all of these, we're removing the* `onclick` *from the markup:*

You can use a data attribute, like this:

```
<a class='more' href='#' data-id='<?php echo $showInfo["bID"]; ?>'>mer</a>
```

Then grab it in your [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler, like this:

```
$('.more').click(function () {
  $('#MoreFriendInfo'+$(this).attr('data-id')).toggle();
});
```

Alternatively if it's in another container forget the IDs and [find it relatively](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), for example if the markup was like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <a class='more' href="#">mer</a>
   <div class="moreFriendInfo">Content</div>
</div>
```

You could do it like this:

```
$('.more').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.container').find('.moreFriendInfo').toggle();
});
```

(In this case you can actually use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), but it's meant to be a more general approach)

Comment: Thanks while waiting on accepting your question i got an question. Can you specify any attr name you want? (to your first solution)

Comment: @Karem - They should start with the `data-` prefix, other than that yes, whatever you want, they don't do any harm in HTML4, and they're actually part of the spec in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are defining it, `test(id)` is an inner function that is only scoped within `.click()`.

Note that when you use .click(), you are effectively defining onclick.  You don't need to add it to the markup also.

Rather than passing the id, I would design the markup in such a way that the elements were placed in such a way that I could use selector context to pass a starting point for the selector.

`$('.more').click(function () { $('.moreFriendInfo',this).toggle(); });`

Comment: This approach would find a `class="moreFriendInfo"` element *inside* the anchor, which doesn't appear to be the case :)

Comment: @Nick, please see what I said above the code "rather than passing the id".  The code could also use a selector of $(this).parent().  **There is no reason to do a full dom search in a case like this.**

Comment: @rchern - I never said search the entire DOM :) See my answer, something like `$(this).siblings()` or `$(this).closest('selector').find('selector')` is what I was talking about.

Comment: @Nick, I understand, but my answer already mentioned looking at the design of the markup prior to your comment.  Using $(this).closest('selector').find('selector') seems like it isn't the most optimized way.

Comment: @rchern - It goes up to the container and finds the "more" to show within the container you're in...if you have say 200 of these on a page....you have a more optimal way? :)  The point was to find it relatively, in as few steps as possible, of course I agree to not do any extra work. I was simply commenting that a `this` context selector is hardly ever applicable in a "view more" context....I've never seen the "more" also contained *inside* the link  :) (though it's surely possible...)

Comment: @Nick, I've seen code (and not mine :p) that puts the click event on a container div if that div is only going to contain the single link with its 'more' container.  The event bubbles up from the a to the container div and `this` works as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer is almost perfect, but I'd use "rel" instead of "data-id" unless data-id is a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: They are valid attributes, `data-anything` is reserved for those attributes you wish were there but never had :)